# What alternative do I have to run a scheduled task

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I have hacked together a fix for running a scheduled job on my web server that has worked well enough up until now.

I had the need to run a job every `x` minutes on my IIS 7 box. To accomplish this, I created a webpage (runcronjob.aspx) that contains all of the logic that I want to run, checks job times in the database, last run time, send emails, query active directory, etc. I then used Task Scheduler on my workstation (not the web server) to call the page I made. I no longer have a dedicated workstation that will always be on the network, so I'd like to move the scheduled task to the web server and this is where I'm getting stuck.

The web server is a Windows 2008 x64 machine running IIS 7. I tried to create the scheduled task on the web server the same way as I did on my local machine but it does not work. The scheduled task calls `IEXPLORE.EXE` with the webpage as the parameter "http://mydomain.com/cron/runcronjob.aspx". When IE 7 launches on the web server, it prompts for a username and password. I also tried running a vbs script locally on the server:

**runjob.vbs**

```
Call LogEntry()

Sub LogEntry()

        'Force the script to finish on an error.
        On Error Resume Next

        'Declare variables
        Dim objRequest
        Dim URL

        Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

        'Put together the URL link appending the Variables.
        URL = "http://mydomain.com/cron/runcronjob.aspx"

        'Open the HTTP request and pass the URL to the objRequest object
        objRequest.open "GET", URL , false

        'Send the HTML Request
        objRequest.Send

        'Set the object to nothing
        Set objRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

The problem that I've run into with this scenario is that I have forms authentication setup on website. So when this script is ran, it redirects to the log in page instead of running the code on runcronjob.aspx.  To get around this, I added this code to the code behind of the Page_Load secton of the login page:

```
If Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR") = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") Then
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("AD-ENT\accountToRunAs", False)
End If
```

The login page executes the code, but it never redirects back to the runcronjob.aspx for that code to run.

I'm starting to run out of ideas.

**EDIT:**
The reason why I'm doing it in such a 'hacky' method is because I have very limited access to the web server and it was like pulling teeth even getting permission to let me run a scheduled task on the server.  That being said, options like creating a console app or a Windows service to run could prove to be difficult.

Comment: Aside from opening IE, what is this scheduled task supposed to do?

Comment: @zeroef, instead of using the Windows Task scheduler to call the web page which does the job, move the logic of the job execution from that asp.net page to a small application, like a console application, and call such application at every x minutes using windows task scheduler.

Comment: can you kill iexplore.exe at the end of your vbs?

Comment: david is right. use vb express or pro to write a simple console app.

Comment: @Davide and Amit - See my edit.  The reason why I have all my logic running on a webpage is because I know I will always have access to modify it.  I do not have admin permission on the web server. :(

Comment: then make a small exe in VB.NET or C#, a console application which instantiates a WebRequest to that page so the web server will load and execute the page, no need for Internet Explorer or any UI for that. But it's anyway an hacky way :(

Comment: @Davide - Isn't that what my runjob.vbs script does? How would that differ? Would I still run into the redirect issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that it requires such a hack to use IIS as opposed to a Windows Service for scheduling...but the best answer I've found in the past is still this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx

As for handling authentication - you could expose the AuthenticationService in your IIS website and then use wininet to SetCookie using the response from the authentication service...that would make your GET request succeed without redirection to the logon page.., References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385326(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.applicationservices.authenticationservice.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your scheduled task should not need to access the web application at all if all you're doing is database maintenance.

Create a console application that performs the necessary database work, and use a scheduled task to run the console application at specified intervals.

**EDIT**

> "options like creating a console app or a Windows service to run could prove to be difficult"

If a console app is not a possibility, use a scheduled task to run a script which updates the database. The main point here is that whatever solution you choose, you should be accessing the database directly rather than using the web application to interface with the database.

**EDIT**

> "It does more than just work with the database. It also sends out emails, does some things with Active Directory - not just database actions."

You can also use the script(s) to perform other actions, such as sending out emails, updating active directory, etc.

Comment: Bravo, exactly what I suggested in my comment :)

Comment: +1 for a great suggestion, but this isn't a feasible option. Added more info to my question.

Comment: @James - Sorry for being vague in my original question. It does more than just work with the database. It also sends out emails, does some things with Active Directory - not just database actions.

Comment: @zeroef: These are all things you can do from within a script.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to move all your logic to a console application and put it in an infinite while loop.

Once this becomes stable you should rewrite it as a windows service and set it start up with windows (i.e. without login).

Comment: so it is okay to write scripts, but not services?  what do you do if the server is rebooted.  all the scheduled tasks will start only if someone logs in to the server.  you website will come up, and all the background services will start without that.

Comment: That's not true. There is a setting to run tasks without a user logged in. If what you're saying were true, scheduled tasks would be essentially useless.